# i18n assets management / translation UI

Tags: ruby, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, rubygems

i'm building a multi-lingual webapp with i18n from the ground up, and while i myself can deal with an army of yml files, the languages i speak are ( very ) limited, and would eventually like to ask for outside help.

I'd like to know if anyone here is using a UI plugin/gem ( not unlike django-rosetta on django ) to deal with multiple translators, some of them unwilling or unable to mess with 100+ files in a repository, working on language data.

thanks &regards,
Andras

( apologies if you bumped into this on rubyonrails-talk already )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [rails3 branch of the tolk gem](http://github.com/dhh/tolk/tree/rails3) on github.  You can install it by inserting the following line in your Gemfile

```
gem "tolk", :git => "http://github.com/dhh/tolk.git", :branch => "rails3"
```

Answer (score 3):

We used the [translate](http://developer.newsdesk.se/2009/01/21/translate-new-rails-i18n-plugin-with-a-nice-web-ui/) gem for one of our projects before and it worked nicely. It's not perfect as your YAML files are no longer in your SCM but it lets the client translate his own application. We only used one YAML file per language so I don't know if it scales to a few 100 files...

DHH created another one, [tolk](http://github.com/dhh/tolk), but I didn't have a chance to look at it yet.

Both solutions are for Rails 2.x, haven't tried this in Rails 3 yet.

Comment: Thanks! I had a quick look at both. Tolk seems not to be rails3 ready, or the migration generator has gone MIA, Translate starts up fine, it has minor issues with output ( raw ) but other than that, it looks good. I will have to test if it saves back to my multiple files appropiately - i suppose it should.

Comment: Too bad, well, good to see there is a Rails 3 branch for tolk. Will have to try that one as well. Thanks for your question I'm looking for a solution as well.

Answer (score 2):

Although this might be a bit late, the [phrase service](https://phraseapp.com) looks like something that suits your need. They provide i18n management through in-place edit.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 3, the URL for tolk is just http://github.com/tolk/tolk and installation is as simple as adding

```
gem "tolk"
```

to your Gemfile and running `bundle install`.